# How to prove independence of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

What are the common approaches for proving it?

Do we need to consider joint PDF?

For example, let $A$, $B$, and $C$ are independent random variables.

Are $A-B$ and $B-C$ are independent?

Are $A$ and $AB$ are independent?

Thank you.

Comment: What does your intuition tell you? The answer is NO for both.

Comment: Intuition tells me yes for the first and yes/no for the second (depends on the distribution). But what is the formal approach to prove this?

Comment: $B$ appears in both $A-B$ and $B-C$. Why do you expect these to be independent?

Comment: Just intuition. If A and B are independent, then subtracting the "same" doesn't change independence. Like A-1 and B-1 are independent.

Comment: As a simple example suppose A, B and C are rolls of 3 different dice. If A-B is -5 you know B-C can't be negative, but if A-B is 5 you expect B-C to be negative more often than not. For the other one, you can't get AB=36 unless A=6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ B\ $ has positive variance, $\ \sigma_B^2\ $, then
\begin{align}
\text{cov}(A-B,B-C)^\color{red}{\dagger}&=\text{cov}(A,B)-\text{cov}(A,C)-\sigma_B^2+\text{cov}(B,C)\\
&=-\sigma_{B}^2\\
&<0\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ A-B\ $ and $\ B-C\ $ are not even *uncorrelated*,let alone independent.

$\left.\right.^\color{red}{\dagger}$ Here, $\ \text{cov}(X,Y)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}E\big((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))\big)\ $ is the [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $.